# Chrome real direct download

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Looking for a way to blindly download ressources from chrome and disallow showing file in page.

Problem happens for file types like .ttf or .woff that don't directly go to the chrome's download manager, but are displayed instead. Saving this view makes the output file being converted to .htm. I'd like to download the original file from server.

Comment: Please clarify your purpose and narrow down the wide set of tags on your question. Users generally don't want surprise files appearing on their system, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: done. Sure they don't want it to happen by default, but what if they want to sometimes ?